How do i make the categoryfilter to work dynamically and also only show the parents categories and nothing else?
So i have stumbled on to a situation while buildning my wordpress/ woocommerce webshop that im buildning with Elementor Pro.
I need someone smarter then myself to help me write the correct SQL Query so that on my frontend inside the elementor product archive the filter only show the parent categories and no other categories and also work dynamically so that when I'm inside a specific grandparent category, for this example, lets call the grandparent category "DOG" and the parent categories are then, multiple categories, like dog food, dog treats, dog leach and so on. inside of the child categories of each parent shows the product, so they would the be called, dry dog food, dental dog treats, leather leash and so on. I only need the filter to show me the parent categories and work dynamically so that when visiting "DOG" - "dog food" - "dry dog food" here ill se only parents of dog categories. at the moment all my child categories is showing on the filter and there's a lot of them as i have 6 different grandparent categories and around 10 to 15 parent categories for every grandparent and then maybe 5 to 10 child categories for every parent category. Please help me get to were i need to be to solve this, I'm getting frustrated as i spent countless hours on this already.
For the query I'm using Crocoblock Jet engine plugin and for the filter I'm using jet smart filter plugin. Which i bought thinking that this was gonna be relatively easy to do with them, haha! Turns out that there support ain't helping me with this as it's to big of a challenge for them.
I have tried everything my knowledge can comprehend. but as i explained in my question i have reached my limitations and cant figure this out by my self.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is more likely to get a useful answer if you can edit it to show the schema (table definitions) of your database along with some sample data showing how the relationships between products, categories, sub-categories and sub-sub-categories are modelled. Please add a minimal reproducible example showing the query you've already tried and how its results differ from what you're expecting.
